# Wrapfigure in a headerbox

Tags: wrapfigure, baposter

I have a poster (baposter) with 3 columns and headerboxes and I want to use the \wrapfigure function so that my text wrap around my figures. The function doesn´t seem to work within a headerbox. I have also tried to use minipage but with the same result. I would really appreciate some help with this.
for example:

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0paper,fontscale=0.31]{baposter} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,span=2, row=0}{

\lipsum[1-2]

 \begin{wrapfigure}[R]{0.5\linewidth}       \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{metal_concentration.png}
   \end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[3-4]
}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: IIRC wrapfigure only works in outer par mode.  Nor does it get along with \lipsum (use \LipsumPar instead).  There are alternatives to wrapfigure.

Comment: Alas, Miktex doesn't support baposter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, Nope. It works, but will not float.

Comment: Why isn't baposter on CTAN? There is xebaposter; is that related?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE. The main changes are:

1. Include values for the left and right logos (here both `{}`), the `{title}` and `{author}`. These are mandatory requirements for the `poster` environment.
2. Use the correct syntax for `wrapfig` environment.
3. For an explanation of the use of `\LipsumPar{2}` see here: [Wrapfig environment is overlapping text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522158/)

.

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0paper,fontscale=0.31]{baposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  grid=false,
  columns=2,
  colspacing=4.2mm,
  headerheight=0.07\textheight,
  background=none,
  eyecatcher=false,
  %posterbox options
  headerborder=closed,
  borderColor=red,
  headershape=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=blue,
  textborder=rectangle,
  boxshade=plain,
  boxColorOne=white,
  headerFontColor=white,
  headerfont=\color{white}\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  textfont=\normalsize\sffamily,
  linewidth=1pt
}
{} % Left / top logo
{Title}
{Author}
{} % Right logo
\begin{posterbox}[name=introduction,column=0,span=2,row=0]{Introduction}
\LipsumPar{2}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.30\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image: m with]