# Wrapfig environment is overlapping text

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, lipsum

I am trying to write some text around an image, however the text gets drawn on top of the image rather than around it:

[image]

This is the relevant code section:

```
\section*{De Boor's algorithm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/order2.png} \\
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/order3.png} \\
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/order4.png} \\
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]
```

And these are the packages I am using (I suspect this could be a package conflict?)

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperwidth=20cm,paperheight=575cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % generates filler text
```

Comment: Don't use lipsum for the filler text. It has a bug that conflicts with wrapfig. https://github.com/patta42/lipsum/issues/16

Comment: Well, that sucks : p

Comment: You can use `\blindduck[1-]` from `duckuments`. If you give a `-` in the optional argument it'll put a `\par` inside the group and everything will work out fine.

Comment: Did you try `\LipsumPar{1}` instead of `\lipsum[1]`? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[10pt]{6cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[10pt]{6cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{document}` seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@UlrikeFischer told you what is the reason and @Skillmon one way how one can evade the problem. Here is another way which uses `lipsum`: use `\LipsumPar{1}` instead of `\lipsum[1]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[10pt]{6.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}[10pt]{6.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in the second paragraph, where `\LispumPar` is used, the issue does not arise.

Why `\LispumPar`? Let's look at the documentation.

[image]

It basically tells you that one should use `\LipsumPar` instead of `\lipsum` if one is to simulate just text, at least this is my reading of this.

Answer (score 0):

Quick comment for others with this problem.  I was having some strange behavior with wrapfig and text, but not the lipsum.

If you have text in brackets, like this {text}, and then more text that follows, but outside of brackets, then wrapfig only respects the first set of bracketed text.  I'm sure there is a good, technical reason for this behavior, but I don't know it.

Just an FYI for others who might be suffering!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/244992)